# The Same Behavior for Boolean and Exception

Tags: javascript, exceptions, conditions

The following code uses a boolean preference `active`: In the `active` state, it does an operation which could throw an exception. On this exception, it does fall back to the non-`active` state.

```
let active = somePreference;
function getValue(parameter) {
    try {
        if ( active ) {
            return valueStore.query(parameter);
        } else {
            throw {name: 'MyException'};
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return getRandomValue();
    }
}
```

This function can be called several times a second. The `valueStore` returns a positive value on success and throws an exception on failure. (as recommended f.ex. by [Exception versus return code in DAO pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274009/exception-versus-return-code-in-dao-pattern)).

An alternative would be an external `if..else` block to avoid the second exception, but which would have some code duplication.

**How to write clean code with an exception and a condition both triggering the same action?** In JavaScript, that is.

Related:

- [Exception versus return code in DAO pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274009/exception-versus-return-code-in-dao-pattern) says to prefer exceptions to return codes,
- [Throwing and catching exceptions in the same function/method](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/121147/throwing-and-catching-exceptions-in-the-same-function-method) throws the wrong kind of exception
- [Defensive Programming vs Exception Handling?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/139171/defensive-programming-vs-exception-handling) originally deals with python, and
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control once again says that it's okay for Python and stupid for .NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could turn things inside out like this:

```
function getValue(parameter) {
    if (active) {
        try {
            return valueStore.query(parameter)
        } catch (e) {
            // quietly fall back to non-active behavior
        }
    }

    return getRandomValue();
}
```

Now there's no duplication or local exceptions. Should the fall back logic (`getRandomValue()`) fail, you'd always get an exception.